# Database Schema Validation

Tags: database

Im trying to validate if the db schema of about 3000 fields spread in about 15 tables matches the data dictionary(in excel) and also to keep a watch on it incase someone changes a column name or adds new column, i need to be alerted an hence would like to know if there is any easy way to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is through permissions.  Who needs table level privileges?  You can give users read/write access without giving them create/modify table access.  Look at your security model and you will be much happier and safer in the end.